# javascript forEach is jumping to the last item in array instead of selecting relevant item

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Using option tags in html, I would like the user to select the colour theme of the page. The colours are css variables.

My code recognises these css variables and my array. How can I assign each item in the array to an option and instruct the selector to update the variables 'onchange'

Here is a link to a Codepen example:
https://codepen.io/murphyme/pen/JLpoWd

```js
const themes = [{
    name: "theme1",
    primary: "yellow",
    secondary: "green",
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    name: "theme2",
    primary: "red",
    secondary: "blue",
    color: "pink"
  },
  {
    name: "theme3",
    primary: "orange",
    secondary: "yellow",
    color: "white"
  }
];

const selector = document.querySelector(".selector");

themes.forEach(function createOptions(col) {
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", col.name);
  option.setAttribute("id", col.name);
  option.innerHTML = col.name;
  selector.appendChild(option);
});

function handleUpdate() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-primary", this.primary);
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-secondary", this.secondary);
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color", this.color);
 // console.log(this);
}

handleUpdate();

selector.addEventListener("change", handleUpdate);
```

```css
:root {
  --color: #fff;
  --bg-primary: #3498db;
  --bg-secondary: #2c3e50;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: var(--color);
}

.bg-primary {
  background-color: var(--bg-primary) !important;
}

.bg-secondary {
  background-color: var(--bg-secondary) !important;
}

div {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-primary">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="bg-secondary">
  <p>Hello World</p>

</div>

<div class="bg-primary">
  <select class="selector">
          </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in handleUpdate does not have any .primary, secondary or color attributes.

Also no need to have an array of themes when you can have an object keyed on theme. Also no need to have ID on options. Lastly I assume you want to show the current theme in the dropdown

I assume you really mean to do this

```js
const themes = {
    "theme1": {
      primary: "yellow",
      secondary: "green",
      color: "red"
    },
    "theme2": {
      primary: "red",
      secondary: "blue",
      color: "pink"
    },

    "theme3": {
      primary: "orange",
      secondary: "yellow",
      color: "white"
    }
}    

    const selector = document.querySelector(".selector");

    for (const theme in themes) {
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value= theme;
      option.text = theme;
      selector.appendChild(option);
    }

    function handleUpdate() {
      const opt = document.querySelector(".selector option:checked");
      const val = opt? opt.value : "theme1";
      const theme = themes[val];
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-primary", theme.primary);
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-secondary", theme.secondary);
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color", theme.color);
    }

    handleUpdate();

    selector.addEventListener("change", handleUpdate);
```

```css
:root {
  --color: #fff;
  --bg-primary: #3498db;
  --bg-secondary: #2c3e50;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: var(--color);
}

.bg-primary {
  background-color: var(--bg-primary) !important;
}

.bg-secondary {
  background-color: var(--bg-secondary) !important;
}

div {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-primary">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="bg-secondary">
  <p>Hello World</p>

</div>

<div class="bg-primary">
  <select class="selector">
          </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mplungjan . I thought I could call handleUpdate in a forEach initially.